# Which Noda Time type should be used to calculate years/months/days between a specific date and today?

Tags: c#, .net, nodatime

I'm building an application that needs to calculate things like 'how many weeks/months/years are there between two dates' and all my users are from a single time zone.

I wonder, is it better to use `LocalDateTime` for this (because I use only one time zone) or `ZonedDateTime` (to account for possible DST and offset changes)?

Also, am I right when doing

```
LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first scenario, use the `LocalDate` type, along with the `Period.Between` method.

For the second scenario, you *could* construct a `LocalDateTime` like that, but then the resulting value would reflect the "UTC day" - which is an artificial construct.

Whenever you need "now":

1. Start from an `IClock` implementation, such as `SystemClock.Instance`.
2. Get an `Instant` by calling `.Now` on the clock.
3. Decide what time zone you want the "now" to reflect.  Use `.InZone` on the instant to project to a `ZonedDateTime` in that zone.
4. From there, split off whatever component you need to satisfy the scenario you're using.  For example, you could call `.Date` to get a `LocalDate` instance to use with the first scenario you asked about.

In general, try to avoid calling `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.UtcNow`.  Sure, there are places you could use that for short-cutting, but the API won't necessarily guide you to the right conclusion.

To summarize both scenarios:

```
// assuming you start with a DateTime, perhaps from a db.
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2016,1,1);
LocalDate ldt = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dt).Date;

DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/New_York"];
ZonedDateTime now = SystemClock.Instance.Now.InZone(tz);
LocalDate today = now.Date;

Period period = Period.Between(today, ldt, PeriodUnits.YearMonthDay);

int years = (int) period.Years;
int months = (int) period.Months;
int days = (int) period.Days;
```

Also, note that in Noda Time 2.0 (currently in alpha), it gets a little bit simpler:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1);
LocalDate ldt = LocalDate.FromDateTime(dt); // 2.0

DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/New_York"];
LocalDate today = SystemClock.Instance.InZone(tz).GetCurrentDate();  // 2.0

Period period = Period.Between(today, ldt, PeriodUnits.YearMonthDay);

int years = (int)period.Years;
int months = (int)period.Months;
int days = (int)period.Days;
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that in 2.0 you may well end up keeping the result of `SystemClock.Instance.InZone(tz)` around for multiple calls (assuming you want to do multiple things with the same clock in the same time zone) which makes things that much simpler for the "each time" code.